# Upgrade python version in pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am studying pyspark on Ubuntu 16.04.

my spark version is 2.2.1 and python version(in spark) is 2.7.2

I want to upgrade python version in spark to 3.5

How can I do this?